# iTunes filter search results?

Tags: itunes, search, itunes-store

In iTunes, is there a way to filter store search results like in Google? i want to only get apps back from my searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how granular you want your filtering, but there's a panel on the left-hand side that allows you to select specific categories for your search results. There's also a Power Search feature which might have more options for you. In this example, I searched for Wolfenstein and can easily filter out Applications by selecting it in the panel that I've highlighted with a red box. This was using iTunes 9.0.2 on OS X.

[image: iTunes search for Wolfenstein]

Comment: That works, though ideally i'd be able to do something like `category:apps` on the end of my search and it would only show. I was wondering if there was something like that, though that's a decent solution for now.